# How to connect Google Cloud Sql from Website hosted in Godaddy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Now i successfully connect the cloud sql with app engine. I am not interested to get the data via the app engine. Is possible to directly communicate between google cloud sql from website.

```
<?php

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'db_name');

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo "Unable to connect. Error: ".$conn->connect_error;
    $conn = null;
}

?>
```

Please advise me.

Thank you.

Comment: The answer is yes you can. What problem are you having?

Comment: I don't have idea. I am new to Cloud sql. I just update my question. The following script is connect the Cloud SQL from app engine. But if i upload it to Godaddy hositing. How it'll work.

Comment: Start with this how-to article. When you have a problem ask a question - don't forget to include details on you problem and the code. https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/using-cloud-sql-with-mysql

Comment: No problem, glad to help. There are a lot of very experienced developers on StackOverflow. Usually one of us knows the answer or how to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @John Hanley Could you post your solution as an answer for the benefit of the community?

Comment: @PhilippSh - Thank you, I just created an answer for Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud SQL is a managed database service will numerous features to make fault-tolerance, availability and management easy. I prefer this to monitoring MySQL myself.

Here is a link to a getting started how-to page for PHP.

[Using Cloud SQL for MySQL with PHP](https://cloud.google.com/php/getting-started/using-cloud-sql-with-mysql)